# Simulate normal flow for absolute positioned div

Tags: css, css-position

**Please refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xNUKb/7/).**

I need the top of the `#blue` div to remain at a fixed distance (eg 2em) from the bottom of the `#red` header.  In other words, the `#blue` div should be "pushed" down when the `#red` header increases in vertical size (ie as a result of the view-port narrowing causing menu items to wrap).

I would prefer a CSS-only solution, but if anyone can confirm my feeling that this can't be done by CSS alone then I'd also need and appreciate advice as to which jQuery functions I should be hooking, and to which DOM events.

**Notes:**

- The layout otherwise works as-is, except that currently the `#blue` div is (effectively) vertically positioned by a fixed-distance from the top of the grey `#page` div.  This means that as the `#red` header gets taller, `#red` extends "behind" the `#blue` div rather than "pushing" it down.
- The HTML is constrained, with the exception that the order of the `#green` and `#blue` divs can be reversed (within the `#main` div).
- `#blue` is positioned relative to the `#page`, and not by logical flow following the `#red` header, because of my requirement to position its `#green` sibling: The top of `#green` *must* remain positioned by a fixed amount from the top of `#page`.

  I've achieved this (rightly or wrongly) by making `#green` positioned
  relative to the white-bordered `#main` div within which its
  horizontal position is achieved, and `#main` is in turn positioned
  absolutely within `#page` to achieve the fixed vertical position.

  This of course has an effect on the position of `#blue`. I'm just not
  sure if there's a way to "break out" this div away from the other
  such that it's returned to a more "normal" flow.

  I'm not constrained to this approach for `#green`'s positioning
  relative to the `#page`, just so long as the end result for `#green`
  is the same and `#blue` moves down as a result of `#red` wrapping and
  does so independently of `#green`.

Your time very much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="page">page
    <header id="red">
        <div id="menu-container">
            <ul id="nav-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
                <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
                <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
                <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
                <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
                <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
                <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
                <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="blue"></div>
        <div id="green"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    /*arbitrary*/
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0 1em
}
#page {
    /*arbitrary*/
    background-color: gray;
    border-color:gray;
    border-width:1pt;
    border-style:dotted;
    /* necessary - or at least, the achieved result is */
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* both blue and green positioned relatively to this div */
    position:relative;
}
header {
    /*arbitrary*/
    background-color: red;
    /* necessary - or at least, the achieved result is */
    width: 100%;
}
/* necessary - or at least, the achieved result is */
 #menu-container {
    width: 50%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.menu-item {
    margin: 0 0.25em 0 0.25em;
    display: inline-block;
}
#main {
    /*arbitrary*/
    border-color:white;
    border-width:1pt;
    border-style:dotted;
    /* necessary - or at least, the achieved result is */
    position:absolute;
    top: .5em;
    width: 100%;
}
#green {
    /*arbitrary*/
    background-color: green;
    height: 15em;
    /* necessary - or at least, the achieved result is */
    z-index: 100;
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
#blue {
    /*arbitrary*/
    background-color: blue;
    height:3em;
    /* necessary - or at least, the achieved result is */
    width:100%;
    /**** here's the problem - top of blue currently 5em below top of grey page.
    But I want it 2em below bottom of red header nomatter how tall red header is ****/
    position: absolute;
    top:5em;
}
```

Comment: Always quote the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link (not even to jsfiddle, although that's a nice *adjunct*). Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just forget the relative positioning and have `#green` be positioned absolutely from the top of the page?

```
 #page {
    ...
    position:relative;
 }

 #green {
    ...
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top:0.5em;
 }
```

Comment: To clarify, you're saying I should remove relative positioning from `#main`, `#blue` and `#green`, leaving relative positioning on `#page`, and apply absolute positioning on `#green`?  Yup.  That works.  Couldn't see the forest for the trees.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xNUKb/8/

take out `position: absolute` under: `#main` and `#blue`

Comment: Refer _The top of #green must remain positioned by a fixed amount from the top of #page_

Comment: fair enough.. i got a suggestion though.. you seem to have a lot of intersecting conditions.. it makes reading your question fairly hard.. my suggestion is to embed your conditions in the html itself.. ie if i load the html page on jsfiddle.. i can see the requirements for the green box inside the greenbox itself.. that way it becomes more readable..

Comment: The conditions _are_ outlined, but in the CSS ;-)  Thanks heaps for your time though, I really do appreciate the help.  Good advice.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning is probably causing you a headache. But the idea is very simple.

http://jsfiddle.net/vuwzN/

```
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>

#red {
   height: 150px; /* variable height*/
   margin-bottom: 50px; /* fixed distance between red and blue */
   background-color: red;
}

#blue {
   height: 100px;
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but where is the `#green` in this?  The complexity is maintaining the flow layout you've described, while also keeping the positioned layout for `#green`.  Refer _The top of #green must remain positioned by a fixed amount from the top of #page_